# How to define a Python class which accepts type parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-parameter

Python 3.5 introduced *type hints* which allow one to write the following:

```
from typing import Union

answer: Union[int, str] = 42
answer = '42'
```

documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union

I think I understand the naive meaning of the above code. In particular, it means that the variable `answer` has been given a type hint, which says that it is supposed to be of the `Union` type with type parameters `int` and `str`, which in turn means that it is supposed to be either `int` or `str`.

What I do not understand, however, are the formal Python language rules around defining and using classes with type parameters in square brackets.

Can someone explain it?

Comment: Are you saying `Union(int, str)` makes more sense? Can you explain why? `()` is only reserved for tuples, expression grouping, and function calls.

Comment: No, I am not saying that. I am asking what the rules are around using this syntax and how can one define a class which would accept such type parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like any other use of square brackets, `Union[int, str]` is implemented by `Union.__getitem__((int, str))`. In this case, `Union` is an instance of the class `_Union` which defines `__getitem__`. You don't really need to know those details to use the class.

Comment: Oh, so a metaclass is involved! Thanks for the explanation! It makes sense I guess, but I did not realize it is possible to use metaclasses for this purpose. I thought that some new syntax was introduced into the language.

Comment: I'll update the answer; there *is* a metaclass involved, but not for this particular bit. `Union` is actually an instance of the class `_Union` which implements `__getitem__`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. The basic principle remains, I think, the same, i.e. no new language syntax is involved, but the existing language features are used to implement the classes which accept type parameters in the square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Where you use `[]` it is calling the `__getitem__` method. The metaclass of the `Union` type has a `__getitem__` method. When you call `Union[int, str]` you are calling that `__getitem__` method passing a tuple, containing `int` and `str`. You can see this in the `typing.py` file in the Python library.

Comment: Thanks, the possibility to use metaclass is the important piece of information that I was missing.